# SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)

Tags: python, udp, sip, voip, pjsip

I am trying to make calls using PJSIP from my python code. The code working fine until yesterday. Today when I tried to run it, it initially gave me an error that the port is already in use. So I used 
`sudo kill 'sudo lsof -t -i:5060'` to kill existing port occupation. Later I tried to run my code, it gives request timeout error and doesnt make the call.

```
('Call is :', 'CALLING') ('last code :', 0) ()
Press <ENTER> to exit and destroy library
13:02:38.983            pjsua_acc.c !...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
('Call is :', 'DISCONNCTD') ('last code :', 408) (Request Timeout)
13:03:12.214            pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
13:08:50.885            pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
```

I don't understand why such error occur.

Comment: If the same code doe not run now but did before, you should figure out what has changed. We can not do that for you. Also worse a try: restart all devices participating.

Comment: Do you mean to restart the server also ?

Comment: I tried the version which worked for me and posted the same in the forum.

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8 thats funny @KlausD. I am dumb about SIP, if you have faced any such error let me know how you resolved it.

Comment: 408 indicates a problem at the SIP server side. Look for hints in the REGISTER response and SIP server log files. Try restarting the SIP server.

Comment: Thanks Bucq ! it worked, my ip is blocked at the server.